# how to add plugins of ckeditor in nuxt with ssr

Tags: nuxt.js, ckeditor5

i am trying to add Alignment plugins of ckeditor 5 in my nuxt app which is universal (SSR)

i tried like this in plugins

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
import VueCkeditor from 'vue-ckeditor5'

// import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment'; <-- not working


const options = {

    editors: {
        classic: ClassicEditor,

    },
    name: 'ckeditor'
}

Vue.use(VueCkeditor.plugin, options);
```

i also tried direct import to page like this

`import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';`

getting error

> Unexpected identifier

Normal editorConfig is working fine

```
editorConfig: {

      image: {

        toolbar: ['imageTextAlternative', '|', 'imageStyle:alignLeft', 'imageStyle:full', 'imageStyle:alignRight'],

                styles: [

                'full',


               'alignLeft',


               'alignRight'
           ]
         },
         alignment: {
           options: [ 'left', 'right' ]
         },
         toolbar: {
           items: [
            'heading',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            'imageUpload',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'alignment'
          ]
       }
    },
```

Comment: Show full error

Comment: @Aldarund http://prntscr.com/nkn8bm

Comment: You probably need to transpile it https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#transpile

Comment: @Aldarund i never use this and i don't know what is this can u tell me how to fix this? thanks

Comment: i told you, try to add its to transpile option. U are basicallt importing from sources which was transplied. u need to compile them first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best option i finally found than make own custom build npm package and use it like same

Answer (score 1):

You can import/render CKEditor on client side only using workaround with plugin included on client side only which register component for editor

**nuxt.config**

```
plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/rich-editor', mode: 'client' },
],
```

ssr=false makes plugin not to be included in server side build

**plugins/rich-editor.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import RichEditor from '@/components/RichEditor'

// register component from plugin to bypass SSR
Vue.component('rich-editor', RichEditor)
```

And finally import CKEditor in RichEditor wrapper.

**RichEditor.js**

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
```

On server side  will be empty div which will be rendered as CKEditor on client side.

Alternativelly you can register  in your plugin.

Comment: This works well but do you have any idea why when I reload the page (Cmd + R, full reload), I get window is not defined? And not the first time I go to the page.

Comment: @Skoua I guess you have accidentally imported editor on server side.