# NuxtJS: Using a vanilla JS library (Pickr) in a page component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to implement a **vanilla JS library** (specifically Pickr [https://simonwep.github.io/pickr]) into my NuxtJS project.

I use NPM to install it:

```
npm install @simonwep/pickr
```

In my NuxtJS create.vue page I do the following:

```
<template>
    <div>
        ..other HTML elements..
        <span class="color-picker"></span>
        ..other HTML elements..
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import '@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css';
    import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr'

    export default {
        mounted() {
            // code below is taken from Github 
            const pickr = Pickr.create({
                el: '.color-picker',
                theme: 'classic', // or 'monolith', or 'nano'

                swatches: [
                    'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
                    'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
                    'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
                    'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
                    'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
                    'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
                    'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
                    'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
                    'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
                    'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
                    'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
                    'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
                ],

                components: {

                    // Main components
                    preview: true,
                    opacity: true,
                    hue: true,

                    // Input / output Options
                    interaction: {
                        hex: true,
                        rgba: true,
                        hsla: true,
                        hsva: true,
                        cmyk: true,
                        input: true,
                        clear: true,
                        save: true
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
</script>
```

When I navigate to the page that I import this plugin, I get the following error:

[image]

## Question 1:

I assume that this is happening because it's trying to find the `<span class="color-picker></span>` that is not there yet. I thought that "mounted" is executed after the template is rendered. What I am not understanding here? How do I solve this?

## Question 2:

Is there a proper way of using a vanilla JS library as a plugin? I read this https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/ but it's not clear to me which case this is. Obviously, this is not a Vue plugin, but it's an ES6 plugin that is located in node_modules. So how do we tackle this, if we want to have access to this plugin from every page?

## Question 3:

When I restart the server (CMD+C, npm run dev [both server and client compile OK]), and visit http://localhost:3000/dashboard/ageRanges/create, the library works just fine.

[image]

If I reload that page, I get the previous error.

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: I tried creating a codesandbox with that package, but it just messes up the sandbox. But somethings you could try are. 1. use a `$ref` for `el` instead of a class, not sure if that would help but something to consider. 2. Use a global mixin, which will allow you to reference `this.Pickr` anywhere.

Comment: Stacktrace from server could help. to see what reference is giving error. Anyway mounted() is really called when element already exists. As mentioned in comment above referencing by just class is not good idea. I would recommend using $el to get component root (and ideally wrap pickr alone to own component although you can eg use this.$el.querySelector('.color-picker')

Comment: @farincz Trying to use this.$el.querySelector('.color-picker') within my method, it works, but when i reload the page i get the same error again (500 referenceError) and "window is not defined". I am also using the old syntax (not the arrow functions) to make sure that "this" is called and still the same issue.

Comment: If i comment out importing both pickr css and js files, and use the console.log(this.$el.querySelector('.color-picker')) then i don't get the error even if i refresh the page. So the problem appears when reloading the page and importing the css/js again.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Picker itself is accessing window. So even import in server side mode cause error.

This can be solved, but it's tricky. You basically need to move import to plugin which will be loaded only in client mode.

You can use same approach as I proposed in following answer
[how to add plugins of ckeditor in nuxt with ssr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991788/how-to-add-plugins-of-ckeditor-in-nuxt-with-ssr/58141640#58141640)
(it's same problem, library is accessing window object)

Comment: So basically i create a pickr.js plugin with import Vue from 'vue'; import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr'; Vue.component('pickr', Pickr); then in nuxt.config.js add it into plugins {src: '@/plugins/pickr', mode: 'client'}. After this how do i use it?

Comment: @christostsang Register global component, eg <color-picker> (IN PLUGIN). Then use it in your view (no addtional import is here). For server, it is just uknown tag rendered as unknow element. for client it's tag bound to your registered component so vue render component here. And you effectively moved import to place where is imported only on client side.